# Abp.io Angular UI - ListService with custom property filter

Tags: angular, abp

Abp.io platform comes with integrated [ListService](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/UI/Angular/List-Service) that simplifies the use of [ngx-datatables](https://swimlane.gitbook.io/ngx-datatable/) in Angular UI of abp platform.

The question I'm having is:

**How to do filtering in ListService with some custom property?**

*Example:
Entity_A has list of Entity_B.
I want to show table of Entity_B for some given Entity_A.*

So I need to somehow add id of Entity_A in this code to trigger filtering based on this Entity_A.

```
const dataStreamCreator = (query) => this.dataService.getList(query);

this.list.hookToQuery(dataStreamCreator).subscribe((response) => {
  this.data= response;
});
```

I know I could do custom filtering on UI side when I get the response (data), but in that case pagination could become an issue.

Question is how to do server side filtering.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you `hookToQuery` with `ListService`, it gives you the current query (filter, page, sort direction, sort column etc.) You can add anything to the query as you'd like. Check out the following example.

```js
export class MyComponent {

   // Assign something to this variable somehow
   someFilterValue;
   data;
   
   constructor(public list: ListService) {
      const dataStreamCreator = (query) => this.dataService.getList({
         ...query,
         ...this.someFilterValue
      });
      this.list.hookToQuery(dataStreamCreator).subscribe((response) => {
         this.data= response;
      });
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

More comprehensive answer on this: This all about **Extending query with custom variables**

You can find a detailed answer [here](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/UI/Angular/List-Service#extending-query-with-custom-variables)